# Is there something like DatastoreOutputWriter?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, mapreduce, google-cloud-datastore

How to write back MapReduce results to the datastore? My first thought was "DatastoreOutputWriter", but apparently there is no such thing.

Clarification: The question is not about modifying/saving entities. Instead, I'd like to process them, and store the processed results (different kind of entities) in the datastore.

Example: Count the number of users every now and then, and save the results into a new entity containing the date and the count.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The purpose of the InputReader is usually to split the job into tasks for each entity.  You usually write handlers to handle each task which is passed the appropriate entity.

You don't really need a DatastoreOutputWriter since you can simply write the entity in the task.  The mapreduce lib has some tools to make it a bit more efficient by using async Puts.  They're recommended but code that doesn't use them will still work.  Here's a very simple handler that makes a small modification and writes the entity back in the mapper phase:

```
def addNewAttribute(entity, *args, **kwargs):
    try:
        if not entity.get("newattribute"):
            entity["newattribute"] = False
            yield op.db.Put(entity) # save the entity back to datastore
            yield op.counters.Increment("touched") # use mapreduce counter to track operations
    except: 
        yield op.counters.Increment("touchFail")
```

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want to modify the same entities. Instead I want to process them, and save the results of the processing to the datastore. See the clarified question.

Comment: Re-reading dragonx's answer: I guess I can just write to the datastore from the reducer using op.db.Put.